# How to identify counterfeit Shimano parts?

Tags: shimano, parts

I bought a pair of Shimano brifters from eBay, brand new.  They have a few bumps and marks on the plastic and metal parts that look like poor quality manufacturing to me.  Can anyone tell from these photos whether these are legit?  The model is Acera ST-EF65.

My tinfoil hat is on because they shipped from China, brand new without original packaging.

I was thinking maybe a good test is to dip the cables in water for a few hours and see if they rust.  To see if they are truly stainless.

Update:  While installing this, I noticed it does not have a hole to adjust brake pull between V or caliper style.  The [dealer manual](https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-ST0001-05-ENG.pdf) says it should have this.  Hmm...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: As far as I'm aware Shimano have manufacturing plants in Kunshan, Malaysia and Singapore, it's noted on other forums and the general web that stuff coming out the Malaysian and Singapore plants is a lower quality. It looks like your's say Indonesia on them, it's entirely possible that they're genuine Shimano but the QC isn't as good hence the markings and bumps.

Comment: The lack of packaging isn't necessarily suspicious. Parts intended for retail come in packaging; parts intended for manufacturers to put on new bikes ("OEM parts") don't, since a factory making thousands of bikes doesn't want to have to take thousands of brake levers out of thousands of boxes. The OEM parts are cheaper (bulk discount and no packaging) so many budget retailers buy them to sell to the public.

Comment: By the way, those aren't brifters. A [brifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimano_Total_Integration) is a single lever that controls both the gears and a brake.

Comment: Oh! Ok. I thought the term just means brakes and shifter in the same unit

Comment: It look to be a Altus or lower spec component. At this price point they sell for (guessing no more than $US30 retail) the rough edges come for free.

Comment: In addition to what @DavidRicherby said, does anyone think it's possible that these were shifters rejected at quality control?

Comment: @WeiwenNg I doubt it. The whole point of quality control is to reduce the amount of inferior product leaving the factory. In some cases, QC failures are sold as "seconds" but, usually, a large company will want to protect its reputation by keeping QC failures off the market.

Comment: @DavidRicherby that was exactly what I was wondering, actually. I am thinking that **perhaps** these were QC rejects, but an unscrupulous seller somehow obtained them and sold them on eBay. so, they might not be counterfeits, but they shouldn't be on the market (albeit maybe the imperfections are cosmetic only, but the user has no way to be sure of this)

Comment: If you drip them into water for several hours, you may easily discover that even stainless steel does rust.

Comment: Ok, so there are 5 net upvotes to the question (one of them is mine) but no answers. I suspect this is one of those questions that is going to be hard to answer. I have a hunch that Shimano could identify a counterfeit or QC reject product based on serial numbers or lack thereof, but it might be hard for end users to tell.

Comment: @ElliottB Shimano plain gear cables are steel without a galv finish so if they do rust (nice and evenly) they probably are genuine. The head of shimano gear cables is usually stamped with an S mark if you want to check that.

Comment: How does one avoid buying counterfeit products in the first place? Does Shimano have any official dealer system, or watermarks on their packages (however effective) like the SD card companies do? I recently bought two Shimano derailleurs on Amazon and didn't think twice about it. But now I don't know if they are real or not. Is it necessary to avoid eBay and Amazon completely, or is there some way to check if parts are genuine?

Comment: @BetterSense Amazon itself is ok. But Amazon sellers are bad. It's best to avoid them. No way to check before buying, but things that aren't available from reputable sellers but are readily available on Amazon/eBay/AliX are usually fake.

Comment: @DavidRicherby maybe I'm mistaken, but this unit does control both a brake and a shifter.

Answer (score 3):

If you are really interested you could contact Shimano directly, say that you bought them, that they do not have adjusting hole, and that you suspect they may be counterfeit, and if they could advise you how to check it. I suppose they would be happy to help you out since it is in their interest to find and fight counterfeits.

But you could be looking at the wrong instructions (like year of production). Parts could have originated from some new bike, that was upgraded in the shop with some higher spec parts, and originals got sold this way.

Comment: As someone who has purchased similar fake Shimano parts on eBay from China, the quality issues are immediate and glaring; if you have some experience handling bike parts, it's clear they are not any kind of Shimano parts.

Comment: @Armand, there are I think different grades of fake. But some of the comments in this thread 'what do you expect for $30' are very wide of the mark. There is a lot of fake stuff out there. The smart conclusion is that if you bought something that seems off and you aren't certain about its provenance then it's probably fake

Answer (score 2):

I purchased some off ebay that look like yours, even with similar label, I can't be 100% sure but but suspect they would not be genuine.

Points that suggest my parts are not original:

- The mouldings have a rough surface, not smooth
- the high/low text is not moulded into the lever, just printed on
- the paint/chrome is applied unevenly
- they just feel sloppy, with loose tolerances
- some of the pieces/mouldings having sharp edges, meaning they've skimped the finishing processes by inadequate deburring or tumbling.

Mine didn't work properly from the start, the bolt through the middle was loose and it didn't change into high gears.  And the whole thing fell apart when I twisted it the wrong way while investigating.

Lesson for me is to be sure of genuine/quality parts before purchasing anything, or money just wasted.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Do you have any reason to believe that the issues mentioned are indicative of counterfeit rather than poor quality control? You say that the lesson is to ensure that parts are genuine moving forward. How are you going to do that?

Comment: The fake Shimano Deore-level rear derailleurs I bought on eBay had paint that easily scratched off with my fingernail, rough casting ends/edges. were missing some small ridges (e.g. by cable attachment screw), had off-center borings and some non-standard-looking bolts. Having many such issues on one part as well as missing/extra features make clear it's not just a QC issue.  It's much harder to spot stuff like the wrong metal or plastic, so comparing the fine details with photos of the real item is probably the easiest way to identify a fake and prove it to the vendor so they will refund you.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you got the fake product. Currently, fake Shimano parts from China are also flooding Indonesia‘s Online marketplaces. We can see the difference from: quality, material, weight, price,etc.

To prevent receiving any fake product in Online marketplace, I usually ask clarification from the seller & review the comments before buying it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Warnings about counterfeit parts are useful, but it would be even more useful to pass on details of how to tell they are counterfeit.  What about these tells you that?

Comment: @DavidW there is a similar question here: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/64791/are-the-shimano-derailleurs-sold-on-ali-express-genuine-or-fake Usually you can tell by packaging if any (any spelling mistakes will indicate fakes), poor fonts, rough materials, differences to known original, etc.

Answer (score 0):

These are an obvious fake. The 1 in the gear indicator looks like it was done by a 3 year-old. The other numbers are the wrong font also. The writing 'speed' is laughably bad and could not possibly that bad on a genuine product.

The metal strip above the gear window does not meet the edge, like it should, and the barrel adjuster is obviously crude.

The Mega 9 branding is also  missing from the clamp band

Compare this genuine example

[image]

The plastic mark is also missing from the rear of the lever

I found a different fake of this on AliExpress

[image]

This one has developed a 'Low' writing which is found on some Shimano shifters, but not these. The Shimano logos are missing. It's a real piece of crap.